# KeyboardFocusManager.setCurrentKeyboardFocusManager() breaks focus

Tags: java, swing, focus

I overrode DefaultKeyboardFocusManager to provide some special behavior for the Alt key. However, after setting this, I notice that hitting Tab on some of my text fields does not work.

I also experimented with even calling the following on the AWT, but this still exhibited the broken Tab behavior:

> KeyboardFocusManager.setCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(new DefaultKeyboardFocusManager());

Why would setting the current keyboard focus manager have such bad effects?

Comment: what happens when you hit tab on the broken text fields?  also, can you confirm that the text fields work as expected when you dont fool with the keyboard manager?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem as well. While developing a custom KeyboardFocusManager I noticed that even calling:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.setCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(new DefaultKeyboardFocusManager());
```

would change the behavior.

It appears that some early initialization was taking place, and the fix in my case was to set the KeyboardFocusManager before I showed any UI resources. I did this at the top of my application's main() function, and then the KeyboardFocusMangers worked as expected (both the default and my custom one).

Answer (score 0):

You wrote some custom code and now you have problems? Just a guess here but maybe the problem is with your code?

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html).

Comment: I think my explanation was unclear. I created a CustomKeyboardFocusManager that overrode the Default one that is being used by my system. Like you, I started by debugging my custom code. 

However, I noticed that even explicitly setting the keyboard focus manager to a new DefaultKeyboardFocusManager exhibited the same problems. This suggests to me that there's something about the behavior of setting the focus manager that I'm not aware of.